# How can I process all readed items in groups instead one to one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want validate the start and end date of my records that share a producid in a table. I will read all registers in database with `JDBCItemReader` ordering by productId.

This is a example of my table:

```
ID|Name|StartDate|EndDate|ProductID|.....
```

In normal chunk processing, I will read - process items one-to-one and then write them but I want recover a list in My processor while ProductId doesn't change and when this Id change, make some validations and updates to my items and then pass them to writers but I think that this It's not possible because I can't send a list of items to my writers, I have to send them one to one.

Example that I need to do (Pseudo-described):

```
@Component
public class CheckAuxDuplicatesProcessor implements ItemProcessor<MyDTO, MyDTO>{


    private BigDecimal currentProdIdProduct = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private List<MyDTO> currentList;

    @Override
    public MyDTO process(MyDTO arg0) throws Exception {
        if(!currentProdIdProduct.equals(dto.getProdIdProduct())){
            //call to process items (Not implemented yet)
            //return list of items
            currentList.clear();
        }
        currentList.add(dto);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Maybe it's possible if I create a full **Tasklet** class and implement all the logic in the `execute method` (read all registers), loop them and make the validations, edit them and finally pass them to the readers.

Anyway I think that this last option is a bad-design idea. But I don't know other way to make some like this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AggregateItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java) for inspiration. You can use it to create aggregate items (List of items) as groups.

In your case, when the ID changes while reading items, you can consider that your are starting a new group.